# EF6 vs EF Core in ASP.NET Core projects

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I just installed EF 6.2 into my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project. I thought it would be not possible as I read about it in the articles that EF 6 will work with the projects that target the full .NET Framework. But it actually allows me to install it into my project targeting NET Core 2.2

So basically I can use EF core as well as EF 6.2. Just confused

Would you send me some links explaining how it works and what's the difference

Comment: What do you think? Just check EntityFramework.dll's dependencies. Wait for 6.3 if you want EF6 on .Net core.

Comment: Im just saying Im already able to use EF 6.2 with my NET Core. But according to documentation it should not be possible. Just wanna know what I missed